# Elasticsearch Date Range not working

Tags: php, elasticsearch, php-7.1

I have indexed records like below

```
                    [0] => Array
                            (
                                [_index] => test_index
                                [_type] => cool_type
                                [_id] => AVy-s52Kahn1F1gX3B0K
                                [_score] => 1
                                [_source] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => TEST
                                        [name_alias] => 
                                        [webiste] => www.test.com
                                        [directions] => 
                                        [narrative] => 
                                        [office_function] => 
                                        [deleted_by] => 
                                        [created_at] => 2017-06-09 11:03:27
                                        [updated_at] => 2017-06-09 11:03:27
                                        [deleted_at] => 
                                    )

                            )
                [1] => Array
                            (
                                [_index] => test_index
                                [_type] => cool_type
                                [_id] => AVy-s52Kahn1F1gX3B0L
                                [_score] => 1
                                [_source] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => new
                                        [name_alias] => 
                                        [webiste] => www.new.com
                                        [directions] => 
                                        [narrative] => 
                                        [office_function] => 
                                        [deleted_by] => 
                                        [created_at] => 2017-06-18 10:00:00
                                        [updated_at] => 2017-06-18 10:00:00
                                        [deleted_at] =>
                                    )

                            )
```

I want to get only records between the given days (between 2 date ranges and records for last 30 days and records of today etc). So I have written code like this using Elasticsearch documentation [Link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html). But I am unable to get the records.

```
$params = [
    'query' => [
        'match_all' => []
    ],
    'filter' => [
        'range' => [
            'created_at' => [
                'gte' => '2017-06-18 00:00:00',
                'lte' =>  '2017-06-19 00:00:00'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'size' => 10
];
```

Which converts like this while hitting to elasticsearch

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": []
    },
    "filter": {
        "range": {
            "created_at": {
                "gte": "2017-06-18 00:00:00",
                "lte": "2017-06-19 00:00:00"
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 10
}
```

Tried below way also

```
$params = [
    'query' => [
        'range' => [
            'created_at' => [
                'gte' => '2017-06-18 00:00:00',
                'lte' =>  '2017-06-19 00:00:00'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'size' => 10
];
```

Which converts like this while hitting to elasticsearch

```
{
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "created_at": {
                "gte": "2017-06-18 00:00:00",
                "lte": "2017-06-19 00:00:00"
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 10
}
```

Kindly help me on this.

Comment: Can you also share your mapping `curl -XGET localhost:9200/test_index` ?

Comment: @Val added code how it converts

Comment: @Val http://localhost:9200/test_index/cool_type/_search?', array(), '{"query":{"range":{"created_at":{"gte":"2017-06-18 00:00:00","lte":"2017-06-19 00:00:00","format":"dateOptionalTime"}}},"size":10}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will you please give us more data on the mapping that you have created. You might have created the "created_at" field as string, where the range query won't work. The query you have written is looking fine to me. For date field you need to create mapping type as 'date' and format as 'dateOptionalTime'.
Please change the mapping and try again the same query.Please refer to the image attached:[image]

I cannot made  the comment right now so posted this answer.

Comment: I have missed to index it as date it is indexed as string.